# Errors c2784, c2780 and c2676 in Algorithm file solution?

Tags: c++, data-structures

I am currently working on a program for my Programming II course, currently everything looks good, but when I try to build my program. I get the following message in my error list:

```
Error   1   error C2784: ''unknown-type' std::operator -(std::move_iterator<_RanIt> &,const std::move_iterator<_RanIt2> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'std::move_iterator<_RanIt> &' from 'std::_List_iterator<_Mylist>' c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\algorithm    3868    1   ConsoleApplication46
Error   2   error C2784: ''unknown-type' std::operator -(const std::reverse_iterator<_RanIt> &,const std::reverse_iterator<_RanIt2> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::reverse_iterator<_RanIt> &' from 'std::_List_iterator<_Mylist>'    c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\algorithm    3868    1   ConsoleApplication46
Error   3   error C2784: ''unknown-type' std::operator -(const std::_Revranit<_RanIt,_Base> &,const std::_Revranit<_RanIt2,_Base2> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::_Revranit<_RanIt,_Base> &' from 'std::_List_iterator<_Mylist>'  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\algorithm    3868    1   ConsoleApplication46
Error   5   error C2780: 'void std::_Sort(_RanIt,_RanIt,_Diff)' : expects 3 arguments - 4 provided  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\algorithm    3868    1   ConsoleApplication46
Error   4   error C2676: binary '-' : 'std::_List_iterator<_Mylist>' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\algorithm    3868    1   ConsoleApplication46
```

and here is my source code for the program:

```
// ConsoleApplication42.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <time.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

const int numberOfStudents = 9;
string names[numberOfStudents] = {"Abe","Billy","Carl","Dillan","Eddie","Felix","Gill","Herald","Isaac"};

struct StudentInfo {
    string name;
    int grade;



    bool operator< (int grade){
        return grade < grade;
    }

    bool operator< (string name){
        return name < name;
    }
    };



void populateStudentRecords(list<StudentInfo>Students,list<int>::iterator iter, int x){

    for(auto iter = Students.begin(); iter != Students.end(); ++iter){
        iter->name = names[x];
        iter->grade = x++;
        x = x++;

    }



}

bool sortByName(const StudentInfo &x, const StudentInfo &y){
    return x.name < y.name;
}

bool sortByGrade(const StudentInfo &x, const StudentInfo &y){
    return x.grade < y.grade;
}

void displayRecords(list<StudentInfo>Records, list<int>::iterator iter){
    for(auto iter = Records.begin(); iter != Records.end(); ++iter){
        cout<<iter->name<<" - "<<iter->grade<<endl;
    }
}

void displayMaxAndMinGrade(list<StudentInfo>Records,list<int>::iterator iter){
    for(auto iter = Records.begin(); iter != Records.end(); ++iter){
        cout<<iter->name<<" - " <<iter->grade<<endl;
        iter = Records.end();
        cout<<iter->name<<" - " <<iter->grade<<endl;
    }
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    list<StudentInfo>Records (numberOfStudents);
    list<int>::iterator iter;

    populateStudentRecords(Records,iter,0);
    sort(Records.begin(),Records.end(),sortByName);
    displayRecords(Records,iter);
    sort(Records.begin(),Records.end(),sortByGrade);
    cout<<" "<<endl;
    displayMaxAndMinGrade(Records,iter);

    return 0;
}
```

I have tried adding a constructor to my data structure and pasting the code into a new project. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the cause, but I think `std::sort` is expecting a random access iterator. Using `list::sort` might fix something.

Answer (score 1):

As noted in a comment, the standard library `sort` function requires random access iterators. Most likely the errors you're getting stem from the fact that a `list` does not use random access iterators, as as such doesn't supply an `operator-`.

Probably the most straightforward solution is to use `vector` instead of `list` for your container.